# HeadNode,workers Node size details in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

**i am using Microsoft cloud HDINSIGHT**

i have 3 node data cluster created by admin.
when i checked ambari it is showing 500GB used, total space is 1.5 TB
1TB is left over.

how can i know total size of each node and used space of that node respectively using command or Ambarri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

You get the used size/total size of each nodes by using following methods.

**GUI method:Using Ambari Home**

Connect to cluster using Cluster login.

After logging into **Ambari Home**, navigate to **Hosts** and move the **cursor to the each node on Disk Usage**, here you can get the information you are looking for.

**Example:** **50.38GB/1362.95GB(3.7 % used)** [Used space/Total space (Consumed percent)].

[image]

**CLI method:** **Connect to cluster using secure shell (SSH)**.

- SSH into the each node
- Run `du -h --max-depth=1 / | sort -h`

[image]

Hope this helps.

---

If this answers your query, do click “Mark as Answer” and "Up-Vote" for the same. And, if you have any further query do let us know.